# Word for a social partner without romantic connotations?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Is there a good way to describe a social partner without romantic connotations? Especially when referring to dining.

I know date and partner (on its own) generally both generally imply some sort of romantic connotation (feel free to prove me wrong).

Is there anything besides dining partner or friend?

Thanks!

Comment: Dinner companion?  Or is this a more general term?

Comment: How close a "partner" are we talking about here? This could range anywhere from "friend" to "life partner", depending on the level of (non-romantic) intimacy.

Also, are you looking for a word that means "One with whom I am eating"? Or just any sort of term that denotes a connection with someone socially?

Comment: I would just use the word *friend*! If you want a different answer, you should explain why friend doesn't fit.

Comment: I'd avoid overusing it, but you could say "platonic friend" if you wanted to make sure no one jumped to a wrong conclusion about the nature of the relationship.

Comment: Especially for a male friend, _buddy_.

Comment: *Social partner* has no "romantic connotations." That phrase sounds rather odd, though. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_partners

Comment: When no commercial or romantic aspect is present, why *partner*? Not an answer but *companion* is more like it; or, *associate*: (sometimes seen as someone of a somewhat lower rank.)

Comment: I didn't realize that partner implied intimacy as well!
I was looking for both a dinner companion and/or a general term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd hazard that being your [company](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/company) is applicable to most situations, and is sufficiently separate from any romantic connotation which 'companion' might carry. Otherwise, it's largely dependant on the context, and on your specific relationship with the person. You can use vague relationships like 'associate' or 'companion', but these can give false impressions of the relationship, or appear distant/cold.

Answer (score 2):

If you're inviting someone to dine at your own place of living, or even if you're inviting them to dine out with you, you could call them your "dinner guest" (or dining guest, if the occasion is for another meal).  This avoids the romantic connotation, but requires that you be the one inviting them.

You could still use it though, or you could say that you are *their* dinner/dining guest.